# How to access to the user session in Deadbolt2 Handler

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, deadbolt

I'm trying to use [Deadbolt2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) in a play2 application and i'm stuck with the implementation of getRolesHolder() in my Deadbolt Handler.

In the sample application, there is this example :

```
public class MyDeadboltHandler extends AbstractDeadboltHandler
{
    public RoleHolder getRoleHolder()
    {
        // in a real application, the user name would probably be
        // in the session following a login process
        return User.findByUserName("steve");
    }
}
```

My problem is : how can I get the session in getRoleHolder() ?

I've tried to call *Context.current().session();* but I've got the following error :
There is no HTTP Context available from here.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seemingly variable availability of the context is starting to get a bit annoying.  I'll change the signature of getRoleHolder() to take the context.  Check in github in about 10 minutes, and update your Build.scala version of Deadbolt to take 1.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

With this accessor

```
Session session = play.mvc.Http.Context .current().session()
```

More Play1 to Play2 samples at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Play-2.0-for-Play-1.x-developers

Comment: As I said in my question, this accessor gives me a «There is no HTTP Context available from here» error.

Comment: Interesting, then I don't know